# PostgreSQL - Combine select

Tags: postgresql, select, schema

I have a database which stores multiple schemas with tables in it

I want to get every schema name and in the same time check if the schema has a table named 'status'

I got two queries for that:

This query returns all schemas of the database:

```
select schema_name from information_schema.schemata
```

With the returned query I then check every schema if the table 'status' exists:

```
select exists(select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'the_schema_name' and table_name = 'status')
```

My question is now if I can combine these two queries into one?

Thanks in advance
Doobie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a co-related sub-query:

```
select s.schema_name, 
       exists (select * 
               from information_schema.tables t
               where t.table_schema = s.schema_name
                 and t.table_name = 'status') as status_exists
from information_schema.schemata s;
```

If you just want to find the schemas where the table does not exist, you can do that with the following query:

```
select s.schema_name
from information_schema.schemata s
where not exists (select *
                  from information_schema.table t
                  where t.schema_name = s.schema_name
                    and t.table_name = 'status');
```

Comment: Thank you a_horse_with_no_name this is perfect!

Comment: Is there also a way to get the schema_names and only the status_exists who are false? I tried to manage but without success...